# How to stop showing mailto while finding all url's in a string

Tags: javascript, html, css, regex

I am trying to find all the URLs from a string for that I used the following code.

```
Urlify :function (text) {
        var urlRegex = /(http(s)?:\/\/.)?(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/g;
    }
```

It works fine but when it comes to email id it showing **mailto** as well.Which I don't want to show.

<**abc@test.com< mailto:abc@test.com>>**

Can anyone help me to avoid showing **Mailto** along with email id.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated Code/Script**
I think this is what you are looking for

but initially I would remove the colon from this regex section `[-a-zA-Z0-9@%._\+~#=]`

(Apart from the first colon after `(http(s)?:\/\/)`)

```js
document.getElementById("doIt").addEventListener("click", function(){
  var urlRegex = /(http(?:s)?:\/\/)?(www\.)?([-a-zA-Z0-9@%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/=]*))/g;

  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = document.getElementById("links").value.replace(urlRegex,
    function (url) {
      var extraText = /@/gi.test(url) ? "mailto:":"";
      return '<a href="' +extraText+ url + '" title="'+ url +'">' + url + '</a>';
    });
   });
```

```html
<textarea id="links" rows="4" cols="50">
Billions of people abc@gmail.com around the world are still https://www.wikipedia.org/ without internet access. Loon is a network of balloons traveling on the edge of space, delivering connectivity to people in unserved and underserved communities around the world.
</textarea>
<br />
<button id="doIt"> replace </button>
<br />
<div id="result">
</div>
```

**Update change all links except *"Email addresses:"***

```js
    document.getElementById("doIt").addEventListener("click", function(){
      var urlRegex = /(http(?:s)?:\/\/)?(www\.)?([-a-zA-Z0-9@%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/=]*))/g;

      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = document.getElementById("links").value.replace(urlRegex,
        function (url) {
          //Check if url is an email (this regex could be improved) 
          return (/.+@.+/gi.test(url))? url :'<a href="' + url + '" title="'+ url +'">' + url + '</a>';
        });
       });
```

```html
    <textarea id="links" rows="4" cols="50">
      Billions of people abc@gmail.com around the world are still https://www.wikipedia.org/ without internet access. Loon is a network of balloons traveling on the edge of space, delivering connectivity to people in unserved and underserved communities around the world.
    </textarea>
    <br />
    <button id="doIt"> replace </button>
    <br />
    <div id="result">
    </div>
```

Comment: Please have a look at the updated post @winner_joiner

Comment: The non capture group is useless in `http(?:s)?` must be written `https?`

Comment: Can I change this regex to find and change all URLs except mail id's @winner_joiner

Comment: @Zhu I updated my code at the end, this might work, but the regex to test if it is a Email could be improved. it might even be easier, jsut to remove the *@* symbol from the `replace` function regexp.
btw. this is a good website to test regular expressions [Online RegExp Editor](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: In addition is it possible to remove the URLs attached with string like 'Click Me" if user clicked it will redirect to new window with a specific URL. Can I remove that kind of URLs as well @winner_joiner

Comment: @Zhu you would have to change the return statment to:  `return (/.+@.+/gi.test(url))? url :'<a target="_blank" href="' + url + '" title="'+ url +'">Click Me</a>';` or.